# Cordova mac default window height width

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova

I just downloaded Cordova for mac from https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-mac.

I haven't made any changes, so I just load it up in Xcode and hit run, but the first thing I would like to do is specify the window size. I'm not very conversant with xcode and can't find references to the window size, I can't find any nib files either.

How would I set the window size?

*Edit* I used the method described at [How to set NSView size programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472920/how-to-set-nsview-size-programmatically) in my contentView implementation file.

Answer (score -1):

Cordova runs full screen, and depending on the size of the splash screens included in the project will scale to all respective devices.

If you want to embed Cordova in your application you have to look here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_cordova-webview_index.md.html#Embedding%20WebView

Comment: It doesn't run full screen on a mac

Comment: it runs in the IOS Simulator or on the device

Comment: Im not building an iOS/Android application. Im using Cordvoa for mac to build a Mac only application but the window size it gives me is too small

Comment: I ended up following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4472920/how-to-set-nsview-size-programmatically